# pppd loses ADSL IPv6 connection after 30 minutes

Tags: linux, adsl, ppp, pppd

I run a modem in bridge mode and use `pppd` to open the connection. While the IPv4 connection is stable, the IPv6 connection seems to die exactly 30 minutes after opening it. `ping6` starts returning `Network is unreachable` after about 1800 seconds.

The relevant `pppd` config looks like this:

```
# Use Roaring Penguin's PPPoE implementation.
plugin rp-pppoe.so eth0

# Login settings
user xyz@example.com
noauth
hide-password

# Connection settings
persist
maxfail 0
holdoff 5

# LCP settings.
lcp-echo-interval 10
lcp-echo-failure 3

# PPPoE compliant settings.
noaccomp
default-asyncmap
mtu 1458

# IP settings.
noipdefault
defaultroute

# Enable debug info in syslog
debug
kdebug 2

# Enable IPv6
+ipv6 ipv6cp-use-ipaddr
```

There is no relevant information in the syslog after the initial successful connection and assignment of the addresses.

What could cause the IPv6 connection specifically to become unresponsive after exactly 30 minutes? Is there some IPv6-specific heartbeat that I should be sending?